# How to completely disable quick search in GTK

Tags: linux, ubuntu, gtk

I got accustomed to then I write file name in Save dialog in Windows PC, it writes into file name label. In linux I must focus on label, and then write. It's annoying, but I can't find how to disable quick search. I see source, GTK documentation, asking questions to developers, but no help. 
There is this mice hidden? GTK2-3, no matter.

Comment: After changing directory it not focused anymore (((